# Is $N$ considered a proper divisor of $N$

Tags: divisor-sum

I just started Project Euler and I have run into an issue. There are numerous problems that ask about the proper divisors, sum of proper divisors, etc. of a number $N$. Now, before I proceed, I would like to make sure my vocabulary is correct. Is $N$ be considered a proper divisor of $N$? I have always said no, but since it does divide it, is the standard to include $N$ in a list of proper divisors?

Comment: It is standard to exclude $N$ as a proper divisor. Of course, it is a divisor. The notion of proper divisor is little used in mathematics. For historical reasons, it crops up occasionally in problems connected with perfect numbers. Unless $N=1$, the other trivial divisor, namely $1$, *is* considered a proper divisor.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, and yes, the Euler problem I'm working on is dealing with perfect numbers.

Comment: It all comes from Classical and Hellenistic times, when an integer that properly divided $N$ was called something that translates to "part" (of $N$). The "perfection" of, for example $6$ is then the fact that $6$ is the sum of its parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Indeed, the fact that $N$ is a divisor and not a proper divisor is the only difference between the words "divisor" and "proper divisor".

Comment: Like "subset" and "proper subset". :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept it as soon as stack exchange allows me to.